# How to maximize hidden OS disk space

Tags: partitioning, truecrypt

I have a 500GB hard drive, I wanted to put a hidden OS on it using truecrypt.

I want the hidden OS to have as much disk space available as possible. I want the decoy OS to have less space.

I made 2 partitions, 100GB, and 400GB.

I install windows on the 100GB partition and proceed with the truecypt hidden OS setup following the instructions.

I boot into the hidden OS, windows says there is 100GB avaiable.

Why does it say 100GB rather than 400GB? (or 400GB minus the size of the files I copied to the outer volume)